# Run ad-hoc scripts on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Flask application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I need to run custom Python scripts on an ad-hoc basis. I previously used Heroku and there, all I need to do is issue this command using the heroku toolbelt:

> heroku run doStuff

where *doStuff* is the name of my Python module.

Is it possible to achieve this using the eb tool in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Alternatively I assume I'll have to SSH into the EC2 instance where the app is running and run the command directly there. If this is the case, where on the EC2 instance will I find the files of my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you will have to SSH and run your scripts.
Your deployed app version can be found here: /opt/python/current

One another option is to have a custom (and secret, may be) URL mapped to this in your flask app. When you hit the URL, then the execute the required commands.

If on the other hand, the scripts are required at app deployment / server restart, you can use the .ebextensions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands

Here you can setup various actions to be run before app code is run.

Comment: Thanks Sony. The problem that I also have is I can't install Scipy and Numpy using the requirements file. My idea is to SSH into the EC2 instance and install it using the yum command. However it looks like my Flask app is running in a virtual environment on EC2. I installed Scipy now, but my Flask app can find it. Do you know how I can install Scipy (and other packages) using the yum command inside the virtual environment?

Comment: @Johan, you can do this via .ebextensions. Here you can run any command at the time of application/server start. You can use yum command here and install whatever you need. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands